# Changing color of disabled days in a JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, colors, datepicker

I'm using JQuery to display a calendar (datepicker).

I've disabled weekends easily and then I've tried to disable national days.

So here a sample of code:

```
function checkHolidays(date, holidaysArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < holidaysArray.length; ++i) {
        if (date.getMonth() == holidaysArray[i][0].getMonth()
            && date.getDate() == holidaysArray[i][0].getDate()) {
            return ([false, 'holiday', holidaysArray[i][1]]);
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

This is working. But I want to change the color of the cell (the 'holiday' css property) and this is not working. Because I'm setting the day as disabled, the holiday css property is not applied.

But if I do not disable the date, i.e:

```
return ([true, 'holiday', holidaysArray[i][2]]);
```

The css property is working. Got any idea?

Edit:

I've updated my css rule to:

```
.holiday, .ui-datepicker .holiday span
{
     background: none #FFEBAF;
     border: 1px solid #BF5A0C;
}
```

And now it's working perfectly.

This post helped me: [How to change cell color](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-change-color-of-date-cell)

Comment: What do you need more? I'm applying this function in the beforeShowDay property of the date picker. That's it. Maybe you want the css code line? But it's kind of useless.

Comment: I want to see the final output from the plugin so I can see what classes/properties are being applied by both the plugin and the browser.

Comment: I've just added links to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find these useful:

[jQuery UI DatePicker: Disable Specified Days](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days)

[jQuery UI: Highlight multiple dates in jquery datepicker](http://www.emirplicanic.com/javascript/jquery-highlight-multiple-date.php)

[Disable date](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days)

Comment: I've used these to create my code, it's working. I can disable the days I want but I can not change the css property to make the disabled days look like what I want.

Comment: there should be a different id or class for that element you can target using that