# DatePicker with database - changing color of date

Tags: php, jquery, database, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a database with news (date – description – link – so on..)
I would like to change CSS from every date into DatePicker to help users know which date has news.

Here is my code, I implemented a filter. Just need to change CSS to those days are loaded on my database.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(“#datepicker”).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,

beforeShowDay: // need help here! 

onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
var mydate;
fecha = $(“#datepicker”).attr(“value”);
$.ajax({
type: “GET”,
url: “news.php”,
data: ‘datepicker=’+mydate,
success: function(data) {
$(‘#result’).html(data);
}
});
}

});
});
</script>
```

I think I can do it with a function: `beforeShowDay`, but I don’t know how, I am learning jQuery and I was surfing the web without luck until now.

Maybe I need an array to call data from my database, here my script:

```
<?php

$Host = "localhost";
$User = "root";
$Password = "";
$Base = "mydatabase";


$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password) or die("error");


$db = mysql_select_db($Base) or die("Ha fallado la seleccion de la base de datos");

$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT id, mydate, text FROM news"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['mydate'] = $row['mydate'];
    $row_array['text'] = $row['text'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

But I don’t now how to call this into my DatePicker.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: As far as the datepicker goes, take a look [here][1]. I'm not familiar with PHP, so I can't answer the question. [1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084095/changing-color-of-disabled-days-in-a-jquery-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the exact code but this could help

first of all you should find in which format you save the date into database .

if its like 30-1-1970 than you should filter that

use

```
$date=date in database;
$newdate=explode("-",$date);

$row['date']=$newdate[0];
$row['month']=$newdate[1];
$row['year']=$newdate[2];
```

//send this data to javaacript

```
$.ajax({
type: “GET”,
url: “news.php”,
data: ‘datepicker=’+mydate,
success: function(data) {
var newdata=$.parseJSON[data];

//use a loop foreach (datepicker.date as date)
// if keyexixts(newdata);
// $(this).css("whatever you want");

// this is not a exact loop you should do something like that
//change all css using a ajax call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on tracks, but ajax in this case is a little overkill I think. You can just define the array literally in javascript (since json_encode will output a javascrip array) and then use the data to format each day on beforeShowDay. You lose the capability of dynamic updating (you must reload the page entirely to update the datepicker data).
Then on beforeShowDay, return an array with 3 values, as [per docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay)

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var daysData = <?= json_encode($news) ?>; // here you convert your array from PHP to JS
$(function() {
    $('#your_date_picker').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        regional: 'es',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var url = '<?=$url_to_go?>/';
            $(location).attr('href', url + dateText); // I use the select event to do a redirect
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { // date is the day you are formatting, on a DateTime JS object
            //alert( date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDay() );
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            // JS returns months from 0 to 11
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = date.getDate();
            var daySettings = new Array(); // day settings are the settings for the DatePicker plugin to apply to that day's cell // default settings
            daySettings[0] = true; // show the day
            daySettings[1] = 'day_green'; // default css class
            daySettings[2] = ''; // default tooltip
            if(typeof daysData[year] != 'undefined'){
                if(typeof daysData[year][month] != 'undefined'){
                    if(typeof daysData[year][month][day] != 'undefined'){
                        dayData = daysData[year][month][day];
                        //alert( year + '-' + month + '-' + day + '-' + dayType);
                        if (dayData['news'] == true){
                            daySettings[1] = 'day_red';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return daySettings;
        }
    });</script>
```

On the PHP side, you must format the array to something like this, before outputting the JS:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $news[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['day']] = array('news' => 1);
}
```

You probably can also do something like this by concatenation (where the array key is the entire date, instead of an array key pointing to another array).

Comment: Thank so much for answer!

I copied your example but it doesn't work, and the datepicker doesn't show - maybe I have an issue in my php

Here is my code

<?php
// local
$Host = "localhost";
$User = "root";
$Password = "";
$Base = "mybase";

$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password) or die("error");

$db = mysql_select_db($Base) or die("error");
    
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $news[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['day']] = array('news' => 1);
}

?>

Comment: Don't expect it to work directly, it's just an example that you must adapt to your conditions. Specially that php-mysql part. In my case I have a year, month and day column on the table, but you could also have a date-typed column an use ´YEAR(your-column) AS year, MONTH(your-column) AS month, and DAY(your-column) AS day´ on the select portion to have all array elements for that loop.